# Is it possible to make latte-art with a coffee machine that has a cappucinatore?

Tags: latte-art

My coffee machine has a cappucinatore and makes the coffee; milk first and then the coffee.

Is it possible to do latte-art in this way? I've always seen the coffee being first and then the milk second so I'm not sure if it's possible.

I would like to be able to make latte-art while it's normally operating, so no storing the coffee/milk in other containers and then building it later. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 3):

Latte art typically requires you to pour one thing into the other (the frothed milk into the espresso). You could of course try to move the cup with the milk already in it while brewing the espresso in such a way that the coffee leaves a pattern in the milk. But that will be very difficult and will also look very different from normal latte art.

So no, that will not really be possible. You should steam your milk in a pitcher and pour it from there into the cup with the espresso.

Answer (score 2):

As Niko said, the answer is NO. I was not familiar with the cappucinatore, but assuming [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYXsPQ0TzIE) is how your milk is steamed, it is just way too frothy for latte art. Even if you had it poured into a pitcher first and then into the espresso it will not work. You need microfoam, not froth to do latte art.

The long and the short of it is that to texture your milk properly, you need to be able to control how much the milk is stretched (which is simply not possible with this "cappucinatore").